# Finding the relation between two series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My book asks me to find the relationship  between: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(n+a)^3(n+a+1)^3\ldots(n+a+p-1)^3}\text{ and}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(n+a-1)^3(n+a)^3\ldots(n+a+p)^3}$$
Once I find this relationship (which is probably a relation that expresses one sum in term of the other one, plus some constant) I should be able, by giving special values to $a$ and $p$, to deduce the following transformation: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^3(n+1)^3}=\frac{83}{630}-\frac{2^3\cdot3^4}{35}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n^3(n+1)^3(n+2)^3(n+3)^3}$$
I am stuck even at the first point, how do I start?  What's the general approach to solve this kind of problems? (The problem is taken from Knopp's book, in case you want a reference, page 272)

Comment: Have you tried making examples with small values of $a$ and $p$?

Comment: No :( because I'm not sure that will make the precess of generalization easier. Also I think I figured out how to obtain the specialized formula, because it's just a shift of indexes, once the relationship is proven.

Comment: The second expression looks funny.  The denominator has $(n+a-1)^3(n+a+1)^3...$.  Did you intend the increment to be $2$?

Comment: Oh my bad! Of course not! Fixed

Comment: It's more than just a shift of indices. Terms in the first series are products of $p$  terms and terms in the second series are products of $p+2$ terms. Try partial fractions.

Comment: Yes! But how would you use partial fractions here?